# Views disappearing from UIViewController in Storyboard when toggling attribute settings

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm encountering a weird bug where the views in my ViewController disappear if I change any attributes in the scene. The views reappear again if I just toggle that attribute, or modify another attribute. The attribute to toggle can literally be anything, even the tag number for a view.

The views show up fine in the simulator and on actual devices. Just in the storyboard that they're disappearing.

I'm using Xcode 9.2.

Can anyone offer any insight on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

[image: Empty View Controller]
[image: Nonempty View Controller]

Comment: When you change the attribute (and its not showing in storyboard) does it show when you run it in the simulator? Ive encountered a similar bug with text clipping You can check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646425/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called-because-of-ui-tap-gesture-swift-solutio Unfortunately no one has found why these bugs are happening :( sorry to stay im sure it will be fixed in xcode 9.3

Comment: Yeah, the views show up fine in the simulator and on the device. Just in the storyboard that they're gone.

Comment: @GlorytheWiz this furthers my theory then , They should have this fixed in 9.3 just hang tight til then brother

Comment: Thanks Zack, appreciate it. Yeah, it's very frustrating to work with as I'm building my views in the storyboard.

Comment: Interface Builder has a lot of bugs :) I understand your frustration, but still couldn't find any solution or workaroung. Happened to me very often when i was using stack view/custom ibdesignable views.

Comment: This bug has been fixed as of Xcode 9.3.